# When sharing an image with Intent.createChooser, my file disappears!

Tags: android

```
private void share() {

    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/png");

    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
      Uri.parse("file://" + filename));

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Tag"));

}
```

I implemented this simple function to be called from a menu, yet after I call it, the file I shared completely disappears -- it's as if the share is deleting it off of my storage. Why is it doing this, and how do I stop it??

Comment: Having had the exact same problem, I attempted this fix but it didn't help. The one bit of extra info I can provide is that (using both methods shown) It was fine with all the sharing apps I tried except Facebook, which deleted my file in both cases. Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try doing this instead:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(filename));
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
```

Comment: One too many parentheses on the second line, but yes, this did the trick! Thanks.